# How to join multiple lines which doesn't include space at the end

Tags: neovim, regular-expression, macro, multiple-lines, join

I'm working on a subtitle document (.srt) which has thousand of lines. But this issue is not about the subtitle documents, I going to export as plain text to read after. To see the dialogs line by line as a normal sentence, I deleted the dialog number and timestamp lines via record a macro.

But some dialog lines seems to apart from each other. I need to join all the separated dialogs as line by line until the last dot, question or exclamation mark of them.

**Example 1**

```
See the church spire
over the trees?
```

Or end of the line could include comma:

**Example 2**

```
See the church spire,
over the trees?
```

I would like to merge these example lines like that:

**Expected result**

```
See the church spire over the trees?
```

How can I create a macro for that?

Answer (score 2):

Personally I wouldn't use a macro but `:substitute`; this seems to do what you want:

```
:%s/\([^.?!]\)\n/\=(submatch(1) == ',' ? '' : submatch(1)) .. ' '/
```

---

In the find pattern:

```
\([^.?!]\)\n
```

The `\n` is a literal newline, and `[^…]` matches any character not in this group. In this case, anything that is NOT a `.`, `?`, or `!`. For "See the church spire" it matches the "e". We capture this in a group with `\(…\)` so we can add the "e" back later.

So this matches any newline not precedeed by a `.`, `?`, or `!`.

---

In the replace pattern:

```
\=(submatch(1) == ',' ? '' : submatch(1)) .. ' '
```

We use `\=` to start an expression replacement; you can use any VimScript expression here. We check if the group we captured is a `,`, if so we don't add it back because we want to remove that. We add any other character back, as that's the last letter.  We always add a space.

It's a bit easier to read with some newlines added:

```
(
   submatch(1) == ',' ?
       '' :
       submatch(1)
) .. ' '
```

---

So a document like this:

```
See the church spire
over the trees?
See the church spire,
over the trees?
See the church spire
asdf
over the trees?
See the church spire,
over the trees?
a sentence.
another sentence!
woot?
```

Becomes:

```
See the church spire over the trees?
See the church spire over the trees?
See the church spire asdf over the trees?
See the church spire over the trees?
a sentence.
another sentence!
woot?
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and solution. I did copy and paste it what you suggests and the patters are worked perfectly! Now, I being try to understand how this actually working, cause it's a bit complicated for me. 

Comment: It can certainly be a much to take in @Pascowl. I didn't "just write" it in one go, I first made a simpler version which just joines lines, and then I expanded on that to remove the comma (which took me a few tries). It's much easier to really *understand* these things if you write themselves from the start, rather than merely looking at the end-result.